# VSTS build defintion is not picking configured code analysis setting file

Tags: azure-devops, static-code-analysis, build-definition

I am using VS2015 with VSTS and all my projects are configured for a custom code analysis ruleset which is mentioned in .csproj as below.
The ruleset file is kept in the folder where the .sln reside and all projects are referencing the file.

```
</PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\CustomCARules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Everything works perfectly in a local build but when it builds through a build defintion in VSTS, the following ruleset is being picked up.

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static
> Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset
```

I could not see any option to specify custom code analysis ruleset while creating the build definition. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify code analysis ruleset by specify MSBuild Arguments of Visual Studio Build Task. 
[image]
For your issue, the code analysis setting is according to the Configuration and Platform. You need to specify the same configuration and Platform. So You need to check Configuration and Platform you specified in the build definition.

Comment: Thanks Starain. It was my bad. Actually in release mode settings of my solution codeanalysis wasnt enabled. I was always checking debug mode settings but in fact in my build definition I had enabled release mode.

Comment: @user3754877 Since your issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.